# Excel formulas matching numbers

Tags: excel

I have data in column 1 abc 12345-10 in column 2 i have assortment of numbers. If number in column 2 match any number in column 1 i want it to show in column 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Need more sample data and preferably your formula.

Comment: Need a formula that says if Column A contains value in column B then place value in column C. Sample: A shows ACE4567-10 then column B shows 4567 or maybe a different # I need Column C to pull b over if it matches any number in A...i hope that makes sense.  Thanks!!

Comment: What he is asking you to do would be to create a small example of the data and expected output and put that data in your original post using edit.

Comment: Column A (ABC123456-11)         Column B (123456)       Column C (needs to show 123456 if it matches the number in Column A)

Comment: trying to insert a worksheet.

Comment: As Scott said, edit your OP. Also, someone edited it to say duplicate lol. Try `if` and `find`.